# Enabling eth0 or eth1 for internal network in computer without internet access

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtualbox, network-adapter, ifconfig

I am installing virtual box in computer without internet access.
I am not sure this computer has network adapter (Ethernet) or not.
I have two virtual machine which can communicate each other (I create it in my laptop).
I copy the ***.vdi** from my laptop to the computer that I mentioned before.
(Ubuntu Machine)

In the virtual box, I created a new machine with 2 network adapter enabled.
Adapter 1 attached to NAT.
Adapter 2 attached to Internal network.

I do not touch the advanced setting part.

I start the machine. However when I type `ifconfig`, it just show me the `lo`. I can't see `eth0` and `eth1` information.

I type ip addr as suggested by `user*` then it gives me `lo`, `eth2`, `eth3`. Why it does not show `eth0` and `eth1`?

**Why the ported Virtual Machine no longer has an eth0?** (recommended by kmarsh)

Thanks

Comment: I come to a curiosity. Does it means that my real computer does not have physical adapter (Ethernet) hardware?

Comment: Are you asking why the ported Virtual Machine no longer has an eth0?

Comment: @kmarsh , thanks to make it short. Yes, after I move it to the computer without internet, why my virtual machine no longer has eth0?

Comment: What `ifconfig -a` returns?

Comment: @Nikolay Yes Firstly, I had not do `if config -a`. After the problem is resolved, `if config -a` will result `lo`, `eth2`, `eth3`. Thank you very much for your concern. I really appreciate that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your Ubuntu VM CLI and try typing `ip addr`. This will show interfaces that are `ifdown` as well. If the interface is listed there try the `sudo ifup` . If that's not the case try typing `lspci` to see if the hardware is present.

Comment: I try to type `ip addr` and then it gives me `lo`, `eth2`, `eth3`. Why it does not show `eth0` and `eth1`?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. I hope my hypothesis is right. Please correct me if I am wrong.

The problem is because when we create a new virtual machine in `VBox`. It will automatically re initiate the mac address.

Therefore when I load the prepared `*.vdi`, the machine has eth2 and eth3 instead of the prepared `eth0` and `eth1`.

Therefore we should append the `/etc/network/interfaces` file. We should change `eth0` to `eth2` and `eth1` to `eth3`.

**Acknowledgement**

This answer is an reborn answer based on the advice from @user294023

**Add:** When you move your `*.vdi`, make sure that your system will waiting for full network configuration during the start up.

**More Reference:** https://askubuntu.com/questions/82322/how-do-i-fix-broken-networking-in-cloned-virtual-machines/388532#388532